# Why my Content Page node breadcrumbs do not override the ones set for this content type (panelizer)?

Tags: panels

I use a fresh Panopoly distrribution (on Drupal 7) set up 2 weeks ago.

I set breadcrumbs for the content type "Content Page" (Full page override / Breadcrumbs). It works fine.

I created a few Content pages and want to modify breadcrumbs (to display them for these particular nodes). I turn breadcrumbs on for Full page override, modify, press SAVE it saves, but the breadcrums remain the same (in the fields on the settings page, as well as on the content page) - so it does not save changes. 
So in single node settings it shows settings set for the content type and does not allow to modify (it says modifications saved, but settings remin the same).

I did it many times in other cases - all worked fine, but somehow it does not work in this case.

Probably there is some check box somwhere that I missed.
Thanks.

Comment: I found the way.Strange behavior.

Comment: I found the way. 
The sustem refused to save custom breadcrumbs for Full Page Override BEFORE status of this view mode changes to Custom.
e.g. I go to node/24/panelizer, choose full page override -> content and just push save button. Status changes to Custom. Then it allows me to open Breadcrumbs settings and change it.

Strange behavior. Does not look like by design. Hope it will help somebody.

Comment: Please transfoirm your prior comment to an actual answer, and mark that as accepted (that way this question is no longer considered as "unanswered"...